# Rails 3.2 passing parameters from one controller action to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to pass parameters`(useremail,costprojects)` from one controller action to another.

Here is the controller code:

```
 def pdfemail
    costprojects = Costproject.find(params[:costproject_ids])
    useremail = current_user.email
    CostprojectsController.delay.pdfemail2(params: { useremail: useremail, costprojects: costprojects })
    redirect_to :back
    flash[:notice] = 'An Email containing a PDF has been sent to you!'
  end

  def self.pdfemail2
    @useremail = params[:useremail]
    @costprojects = params[:costprojects]
  ...
```

But, I get:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

The delay projects shows:

```
object: !ruby/class 'CostprojectsController'
method_name: :pdfemail2
args:
- :params:
    :useremail: somebody@gmail.com
    :costprojects:
    - !ruby/ActiveRecord:Costproject
      attributes:
        id: 8
...
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass some params while redirecting to another action, use the ActionController::Parameters:

```
def search
  redirect_to :index, params: { query: params[:q] }
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html

Comment: No, the actions does not work like that, they are not meant to be called directly. If you need some logic, that sends the email, and you want to run it in the background, then create a job.